# set selected opntion value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I am trying to create a calculation with selected option and input value, something like this when any user select `option 1` and `input=2`  the output result come with 10(option value)*2=20.
so I write this code:
**HTML**

```
<select id="totaldays">
    <option value="10">option 1</option>
    <option value="20">option 2</option>
    <option value="30">option 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="per_day" id = "mytextfield" value="" />
<p>Total: $<span class="total"></span></p>
```

**JQ**

```
$("#mytextfield").on('keyup',function(){
   // alert('pressed')
        var totalcost= $("#totaldays").val() * $(this).val() 
    $(".total").html(totalcost);
})
```

that is work fine but it's not a good idea to use on series project because  it can be changed from inspector and get the bad output .so, I am trying to get a value by id. I write this code but it's not working :

```
<select id="totaldays">
    <option id="a">option 1</option>
    <option id="b">option 2</option>
    <option id="c">option 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="per_day" id = "mytextfield" value="" />

<p>Total:  <span class="total"></span></p>
```

**JQ**

```
$("#mytextfield").on('keyup',function(){
   // alert('pressed')

    if($("#totaldays").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'a') {
    var getvalue= $(this).val() == '10'
    }
    if($("#totaldays").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'b') {
    var getvalue= $(this).val() == '20'
    }
    if($("#totaldays").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'c') {
    var getvalue= $(this).val() == '30'
    }

    var total= $(getvalue) * $(this).val() 
    $(".total").html(total);
})
```

I am very new in jquery .help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var getvalue= $(this).val() == '30'` in Javascript this will set the getvalue to be the result of the right hand side. In this case getvalue will be set to true/false depending on whether or not the value in the input box equals 30.

I guess you just want to set the value of getvalue to be 10,20 or 30 depending on the option selected in the dropdown and multiply the contents of the input box with that for the total? If so this does that.

```
$("#mytextfield").on('keyup',function(){
    let getValue;

    if($("#totaldays").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'a') {
        getvalue = 10;
    }

    if($("#totaldays").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'b') {
        getvalue = 20;
    }
    if($("#totaldays").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'c') {
        getvalue = 30;
    }

    var total= getvalue * $(this).val() 
    $(".total").html(total);
});
```

Some improvements would be to look into adding a value attribute on to the option elements, which would allow you to remove the if statement in your JS!

Comment: thank you for your answer this work fine. can you give me an other solution that when i input a sum and then select another option the result won't change without changing anything in this input field  .

Comment: That will be because this function only executes when the `keyUp` event is activated on the `#mytextfield`

I'd suggest you look into adding an event handler onto the select element, similar to what you have done already, allowing the total to change when that changes too.

https://api.jquery.com/change/ 

These docs might be of help to you

Comment: I updated my previous comment to include a link to the jQuery docs for the `change` handler, which should provide enough information for you to have a go!